# I have trouble changing treadnulls property at runtime

Tags: javascript, teechart

I have trouble changing treadnulls property at runtime.
I am using TeeChart versions 8 and javascript.
The default value is Dont Paint and I want to put a Skip
The last line of code fails
How is the correct syntax to change this property with javascript

```
TChart1.AddSeries(0);
TChart1.Series(0).Title = "Un titulo";
TChart1.Series(0).Marks.Visible = true;
TChart1.Series(0).Marks.Style = 0;
TChart1.Series(0).Marks.Angle = 90;
TChart1.Series(0).Color = 16777215;
TChart1.Series(0).treatNulls = "skip";
```

Answer (score 0):

The current version doesn't support treatNulls property. You can add null points to a Line series and they will just be skipped. The next maintenance release will include the treatNulls property that will allow you to choose between:

"*skip*": it doesn't draw the point but the line segment between the points before and after the null point is still drawn.

"*dontPaint*": the point isn't drawn and neither the segment linking the points next to it.